# Open app activity if clicked on a specific file in file browser

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to open my activity if user clicks a specific text file in file browser like deep link.
Here is my code

```
<activity
        android:name=".debug.DebugActivity"
        android:label="@string/debug_label"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern =".*\\.txt" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I got the solution with this